# How to remove create an order button in sales order grid in magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, sales-order, order-grid

> i m overriding above code in di.xml file in magento2

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">Knight\Noecom\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: can you please add your overriding code here ?

Answer (score 2):

i just found solution by my own just override your sales_order_grid.xml file and put below code to remove create an order button hope anyone get help from it :

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> //add this line which disable your button
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">sales_order_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Create An Order</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
                <item name="style" xsi:type="string">display:none</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</listing>
```

Comment: Its working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

In sales_order_grid.xml there is code to display button `'create an order'` at line#15

you can simply hide below code in your override XML file line#15

```
        <!--<buttons>
            <button name="add">
                <url path="sales/order_create/start"/>
                <class>primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Create New Order</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>-->
```

run below commands after changes

```
php bin/magento cache:clean && php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: its not a good idea to changes in core files